# Mysql access denied

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so heres the situation. I have just had to move servers due to budget cuts so the new server is a webfusion VPS. I am now getting an access denied error on all mysql queries. This is the specific error:

```
Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I do not know what is causing this. I have a database with the mysql username and password stored in a different php file. The username shown in the error is not the same as the actual ussername and I am using a password. It is my understanding that you can put your own php.ini file in the webfusions root and that will work. Is there something I have missed? I have been running on coffee today so that could be why. The mysql database is on the same server btw.

Comment: go to phpmyadmin and verify that if that user ( which u r accessing ) has actually permissions such read, write etc.

Comment: And show some code. You said you are using a password, but the error says you aren't

Comment: Chances are the variable that you think is holding the password when the db connection call is made is either not set or an empty string. I suggest you echo it out on the line before/after the db connect call is made, and cranking error reporting up to max probably won't hurt: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the appropriate MySQL users after you migrated the database? Grant tables and user privileges are usually not transferred while doing a DB migration (unless you are using some specific tools like the ones provided by Percona etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a couple of things. I guess let's start with what is correct.

Your MySQL server address is correct and your webserver is able to connect to it. This should be a given since your webserver and MySQL server appear to be on the same machine.

The username you are using is www-data. That is the first thing I would check. Make sure that is the proper username.

Now check your password. It looks like you are trying to not have to use a password. Chances are that is incorrect (and if it is correct, you really should think about changing that).

Other than that, there is not much else that could be going wrong there. Are you intending to connect to the MySQL server that is on the same machine as your website?

Comment: Okay, well first of all the username in the error is not what I have n my database file and I definitely do have a password. The database is on the same server and I have no idea what is going wrong.